# script works via command line but not in cron job

Tags: cron

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I tried running this cron job where it should run this script (test.sh) where it copies my photos from one folder to a tmp folder but the cron job does not work unless it is in my home directory (or whatever directory when you just do a 'cd')
I have tried the following and it works via command line but not on cron, can someone help. This is on Mac OS with the latest sw update

```
*/1 * * * *  cd Desktop && ./test.sh
```

I've also tried the absolute path

```
 */1 * * * * /Users/helpme/Desktop/test.sh
```

My code for test.sh is below:

```
#!/bin/bash 
rsync /Users/helpme/Desktop/test/* /Users/helpme/Desktop/tmp/
```

When I have the following in my crontab -e

`*/1 * * * * /bin/bash '/Users/helpme/Desktop/test.sh' >> /Users/helpme/Desktop/backup.log 2>&1`

I get the following in my log file 
`/bin/bash: /Users/helpme/Desktop/test.sh: Operation not permitted`

Looked up the error, changed my privacy to full disk and still get the same error

UPDATE: Thank you to anonymous below in the comments for providing the article that solved the issue. Make sure to add cron to have full disk access. 
https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Comment: Use **full** paths eg: `*/1 * * * * /path/to/test.sh`

Comment: I've tried that and it still does not work

Comment: Send the cron output to a log file. The problem should become obvious. But your script should also be using full paths. What do you think the 'current' directory is when your cronjob starts ?

Comment: when I open terminal and run pwd it gives /Users/helpme

Comment: I have the following in my crontab -e

`*/1 * * * * /bin/bash '/Users/helpme/Desktop/test.sh' >> /Users/helpme/Desktop/backup.log 2>&1`

I get the following in my log file 
`/bin/bash: /Users/helpme/Desktop/test.sh: Operation not permitted`

Looked up the error, changed my privacy to full disk and still get the same error

Comment: A cron job does not have the full context of a user session. But it looks like you may have a permission error, or the paths in your script *are* wrong. They are very likely wrong if you make assumptions about what the current directory should be. Use fully-qualified paths in your script too.

Comment: I added the edits in my test.sh (see above) still does not work properly

Comment: Questions: 1) does the script run from the command line now that you've added fully qualified paths ? 2) is the cron job for the same user 3) I don't understand this: *"changed my privacy to full disk"*. Did you change file permissions ? One thing you can do to debug is comment the `rsync`line in your script and put a `print` instead. So you'll see if the script executes or not and if `rsync` is causing the problem.

Comment: The script works in the command line. When I run the same exact line as the crontab (minus the asterisks since that deals with time in cron), it works. Having it in crontab does not work. How do I check for question number 2. I do `crontab -l` and it gives me my code so I am assuming the answer is yes, it is the same user. For Q3, I am using a Mac and when I looked up the "operation not permitted" issue that I got from my log file, it told me to go into my settings and change the privacy to "full disk". The rsync command works. It fails using `echo hi >> /Users/helpme/Desktop/tmp.txt`

Comment: I am not familiar with Mac but Linux in general. In cron jobs the `PATH` variable is typically not set so it is common to include the full path for the commands as well. So instead of `rsync` you may have to add its full path eg: `/usr/bin/rsync`. If you type `which rsync` you can find the command location. But based on [this article](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/) it seems that the `crontab` executable needs additional permissions to run. Is this what you've done ? I have the impression it's `crontab` and not your script that is failing.

Comment: That article did the trick!! WOW! Thanks so much! I thought it was a permission thing and only put terminal to have full disk access but was not able to find that article and move the cron. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your script works on the current directory instead of an absolute path. In that case the result depends on where it is located. Consider adding the code to the question so that we can help.

Comment: Yes it only works on the current directory. I'm not sure why it's doing that or how to fix it

Comment: that is because you use relative path's instead of absolute. Consider making the paths absolute. That is: instead of tmp/ something like /home/ruud/tmp (absolute paths starts from the root, so with a slash). Only tmp/ means: the subdirectory tmp of _the current directory_. That is why the location where you start the script matters.

Comment: I tried that and it still does not seem to work, see edits for test.sh